# Xcode 5 bot fails to build -- framework not found by ld

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, linker-errors

I am trying to set up my first Bot for CI.   This bot successfully downloads source tree from git but fails to build application (IOS7, simulator mode) which I can build and run without any problems with regular Xcode 5.0.1 environment.

Particularly Bot fails on ld stage (see excerpt below). As I can suggest from the log file, ld cannot find QuartzCore framework, where CA.. functions are defined.

Compiler found all header files from framework, so, for the first glance path are configured OK, but ld cannot find library itself to link...

I suspect this is a trivial error with permissions or environment settings. Could you please point me where to dig?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vladimir

```
+++ +++ +++
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c5e74f8f-f2c8-f2c8-9bba-cc3ce564b8fb/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c5e74f8f-f2c8-f2c8-9bba-cc3ce564b8fb/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c5e74f8f-f2c8-f2c8-9bba-cc3ce564b8fb/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/SBK.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SBKTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBKTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c5e74f8f-f2c8-f2c8-9bba-cc3ce564b8fb/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SBK.app/SBK -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework CoreText -framework SenTestingKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreData -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c5e74f8f-f2c8-f2c8-9bba-cc3ce564b8fb/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/SBK.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SBKTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBKTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c5e74f8f-f2c8-f2c8-9bba-cc3ce564b8fb/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SBKTests.octest/SBKTests Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_CATransform3DMakeScale", referenced from:       -[MBSwitch showFillLayer:animated:] in MBSwitch.o

"_CGAffineTransformIdentity", referenced from:       -[TTTAttributedLabel drawTextInRect:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o

"_CGContextAddLineToPoint", referenced from:       -[TTTAttributedLabel drawStrike:inRect:context:] in TTTAttributedLabel.o

    "_CGContextAddPath", referenced from:

. . . . [skip ] . . . .

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** TEST FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
Ld /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/c5e74f8f-f2c8-f2c8-9bba-cc3ce564b8fb/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SBKTests.octest/SBKTests normal i386 (1 failure)
+++ +++ +++
```

Answer (score 5):

Solved!

It was really trivial issue.

Xcode bot tries to build all targets included into schema. In my case this is project itself and unit tests target. As tests was not developed yet, this target was not compiled. But bot tries to compile it... So all frameworks, linked to the "main target" should be linked to the test target as well.

Comment: +1 for the answer..I also faced the same problem.Linking all the frameworks to my test target saved my day.